# Best way to install OpenCV on Windows with Enthought Canopy Python?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, enthought

I've got the Enthought Canopy Python distribution on Windows, and I'd
like to add the OpenCV python bindings.

I have downloaded the latest OpenCV from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/
but I don't see any setup.py file.

So I'm wondering:
What is the best way to install OpenCV on windows to have it working
under Enthought Canopy Python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I stumbled on this same issue.  Here's what I did:

1. Unpack the OpenCV distribution into a folder, for example: `C:\RPS\python\epd32`
2. Open a text editor and create a one line file that contains the full path where you installed OpenCV + the subdirectory where the python binding lives, for example:    `C:\RPS\python\epd32\opencv\build\python\2.7`.
3. Save this  `.pth` file in your Enthought Canopy user site packages folder, for example: `C:\Users\rsignell\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Lib\site-packages\opencv.pth`
4. Open Enthought Canopy and try typing `import cv2`.  It should now work!

I do it this way because I like having the whole OpenCV distro on my system, with the examples and other stuff.

But if you don't want the whole OpenCV distro hanging around, you could also just copy `<opencv>\build\python\2.7\cv2.pyd` into your `site-packages` directory and then delete the directory that OpenCV unpacked everything into.

Or to avoid extracting everything, you could open the opencv.exe using with something like 7-zip (open inside) and extract just `<opencv>\build\python\2.7\cv2.pyd` into your `site-packages` directory.

Comment: Do not forget to include the subfolder (x64 or x86) for your architecture when using the .pth solution.

Answer (score 3):

Opencv on Windows has been available pre-built on Windows to Canopy subscribers (i.e. in the Canopy repository - https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/) since a few days before this question was posted. Sorry that I didn't see this question before.

Comment: Now available to all registered users, not only subscribers.

Comment: That is fine when you stick to opencv 2.4.x. But for opencv 3.x it is not yet available.