# Enthought Canopy could not find some modules?

Tags: python, opencv, enthought, canopy

I have installed Enthought Canopy Express 1.03 on windows 7 and have recently updated to version 1.1.0.1371 and also setup Opencv 2.4.6 as per the post [Best way to install OpenCV on Windows with Enthought Canopy Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457515/best-way-to-install-opencv-on-windows-with-enthought-canopy-python/17457833#17457833).

Opencv contains few of the python - opencv2 samples in a folder Example: C:\opencv\samples\python2.  Running those scripts inside the opencv directory from the canopy environment works absolutely fine. But when i copy those scripts into other directory and restart the kernel inside enthought canopy and trying to run the script i'm finding an error. 'No video Module Found'. (script name was camshift.py).

I have also changed the working directory to the editor directory option and tried but the results are same. Similarly for other scripts,some modules are not found. Can anyone help me out with this regard?

Answer (score 1):

One diagnostic step would be to compare `sys.path`, in the environment where the example works, vs in the Canopy environment where it does not work. Likewise, though a little messier, compare `os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)` between these two environments. These are the two main locations where modules (python and Windows, respectively) are found, so the difference may tell you what is the key missing piece.