# using cv2 in enhthought canopy to convert an image to grayscale

Tags: python, windows, opencv, 32-bit, canopy

I am very new to python programming. I use enthought canopy (windows 7, 32-bit, version 1.3.1). Very recently I stumbled upon opencv and its capabilities. I have installed opencv but when i use it in a module, i get the following error message. I have installed opencv using this post
[Best way to install OpenCV on Windows with Enthought Canopy Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457515/best-way-to-install-opencv-on-windows-with-enthought-canopy-python)

When i try running this piece of code:

```
picture = cv2.imread("image1.png")
picture2 = cv2.cvtColor(picture, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

it gives an error message:

```
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Let me know if you would need additional info

Comment: most likely this means, that the imread call failed silently, and your picture is empty (None)

Comment: Note that opencv is available pre-built to Canopy subscribers: https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/ . Also note that the current version of Canopy is 1.5.2 (see https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website) though that is not necessarily relevant to your problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can check if Opencv has been added to the list of existing packages in enthought? and if there is a way to check if opencv is getting loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `picture2 = cv2.cvtColor(picture, cv2.COLOR_GARY2BGR)` if it works. Otherwise your image is not in the `gray` or `BGL` categories.